# How to have an array of functions that returns pointers of ints

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, function, pointers

When I try to compile the following line

```
int* x[](), (*y)();
```

I get the error "x declared as an array of functions of type int()"

Comment: I think you want an array of function **pointers**?

Comment: yes sorry. do you know where the error is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for an array of 2 function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *first(void) { return NULL; }
int *second(void) { return NULL; }
int main(void) {
    int *(*fx[2])(void);
    fx[0] = first;
    fx[1] = second;
    /* ... */
    if (fx[0]() == fx[1]()) {
        printf("Calling both functions returns the same value.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot really declare an array of functions, but you **can** have an array of function pointers, which will probably give you the same effect, because you can invoke them without explicit dereferencing.

The following will declare an array of `5` function pointers which return `int*`.

```
int* (*x[5])();
```

The website [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) will let you play with various pointer declarations to see what they mean in English.

Here is the *golden rule* for reading C declarations, stolen from this [old article](http://parrt.cs.usfca.edu/doc/how-to-read-C-declarations.html).

> Start at the variable name (or innermost construct if no identifier is
>   present. Look right without jumping over a right parenthesis; say what
>   you see. Look left again without jumping over a parenthesis; say what
>   you see. Jump out a level of parentheses if any. Look right; say what
>   you see. Look left; say what you see. Continue in this manner until
>   you say the variable type or return type.

When applied to the declaration above, we say:

- x is an array of 5 pointers to functions returning pointer to int.

As SteveCox correctly commented below, we note that if we run into a type qualifier on the left hand side when following the above rule, it will describe the type to its left rather than its right. For example, the following declaration declares an array of 5 pointers to functions returning **const pointer to int**, not **pointer to const int**.

```
int* const (*x[5])();
```

Comment: +1 for [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/). But it's best to learn how to read declarations without help.

Comment: @pmg I hope you mean that its "best to learn to {read declarations without help}" and not that its "best to {learn without help} to read declarations"

Comment: @pmg, I have added the golden rule with a link.

Comment: @merlin2011 with that last edit you left out the fact that type qualifiers (const, volatile, restrict) can land on the wrong side of the thing they describe.

Comment: That's what I mean, @SteveCox :)

Comment: @SteveCox, I added a clarification. Please edit if you think it is not sufficiently clear or correct.

Answer (score 0):

A practical application might look like:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

int add_(int, int);
int sub_(int, int);
int mul_(int, int);
int div_(int, int);

enum    {
    ADD,
    SUB,
    MUL,
    DIV
};

int (*mathOps[4])(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    mathOps[ADD]=add_;
    mathOps[SUB]=sub_;
    mathOps[MUL]=mul_;
    mathOps[DIV]=div_;

    for(i=ADD;i<=DIV;i++)
    {
        printf("results are: %d\n", mathOps[i](3, 3));  
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;   
}

int add_(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;   
}
int sub_(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;   
}
int mul_(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;   
}
int div_(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;   
}
```